# How to combine increment and decrement statements into one single statements

Tags: c

How can i combine one increment and one decrement statements into one single statement in C language.

ex: a++ and b-- into one single statement.

Comment: Depends. Many ways. What actually you want to achieve?

Comment: If `a+b=k` where `k` is some constant, you could just modify `a` and set `b = k - a`

Comment: i just want to combine a++ and b-- statements into one single statement, please suggest me if it is possible.

Comment: Yes: `a++,b--;` (comma-separated) is a single statement.

Comment: Do not throw a XY problem, state your purpose clearly.

Comment: As long as pre / post  / increment / decrement operations are performed on different variables, there is no issue. The issue is if those operations are performed on the same variable in an expression because C / C++ doesn't have strict rules for the order of evaluation of such expressions, so the result is undefined behavior. (In some programming languages, this isn't an issue). So a statement like :  e = a++ + b-- + ++c + --d; should be ok. A common example when copying an array is a[i++] = b[j++];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `a++,b--;`

Two expressions separated by a comma are evaluated left to right.

Comment: ...in an expression context.  That isn't true for `f(a++,b--);` for example.

Comment: However, it would be true for `f((a++,b--));`  (Function `f` would be called with value `b`)